# Настройка роутера TrendNet

Tags: router

Я правильно понимаю, что админские вопросы теперь тоже сюда?

Есть у меня давняя проблема с роутером Trendnet TEW-652BRP и внешним статическим ip. Настраиваю переброс портов. Соединения из интернета роутер перебрасывает на мой компьютер. Соединения из локальной сети на тот же статический ip закрываются с ошибкой. Как сделать, чтобы соединения из локальной сети тоже перебрасывались правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что компьюетер на запрошенные по внешнему адреса соединения отвечает со своим локальным адресом. В то же время клиент ожидает внешнего.

Для работы проброшенного адреса в локальной сети есть пара вариантов.

1) Использовать DNS имя указывающее на локальный адрес. Для большой оно должно быть прописанно на DNS сервере, для средней можно сделать статическую запись в dns-proxy (обычно это роутер), если же компьютеров всего несколько - то проще добавить в `hosts` файл конечных компьютеров.

2) Использовать маскировку, вроде:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.1
```

— в этом случае ответ будет послан через роутер, где адрес подменится на внешний.

3) Использовать DMZ подсеть с другой маской, чтоб заставить локальный трафик ходить через роутер всегда. Например выдать адрес `192.168.1.12/24` для сервера и настроить соответствующую маршрутизацию.

Скорее всего понадобится перепрошить роутер в опенврт или ддврт, чтоб получить эти возможности.